# Is re-using database model in client view considered bad practice?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, architecture, asp.net-web-api2

Let's say I have a User table in my database. In my WCF service it results in POCOs. If I reuse this POCO all the way out to the result of client GET requests. This is the flow:

```
browser/client <-- REST API (Web API 2) <-- SOAP API (WCF) <-- Database
```

Is this considered bad practice? 
If so, why?

The only reason I can think of is that it reveals the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's a trade-off

**Advantages**

- Less code
- Fewer mapping boundaries
- Less conceptual overhead

**Disadvantages**

- **Very** high coupling over **multiple** tiers
- Schema changes are more difficult (without affecting clients)
- Potential impedance mismatch in the web services, because DB concerns leak into the API

Personally, I think it's a bit too much coupling going on over all these layers that you mention. I would only use this approach for a quick hack that doesn't have maintainability requirements.

But you have to weight the advantages and disadvantages for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This helped me see the implications clearer.